# Framework to easily generate an Android app that shows points on a map

Tags: gratis, android, software-development, framework, maps

There are so many Android apps that just show a bunch of points on a map:

- Bus stops of Tokyo
- Public toilets of Paris
- Camping areas of Mount Asahidake
- Rental bicycle stations in Minato
- etc

Is there a framework that would generate such an app in seconds, requiring the user to only enter an app name, a logo, and a list of points?

Requirements:

- Free
- Generated source code does not use any non-open source library

Bonus for OpenStreetMap embedded maps, but using the Google Maps API is also OK.